# LINQ's FirstOrDefault in SQL script?

Tags: linq-to-sql, language-features, sql-scripts

What is the SQL language keyword for the LINQ-to-SQL `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault`?

Is it `TOP(1)`?

EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT TOP(1) @ItemCode = ItemCode FROM VendorItem WHERE VendorId = @VendorId
```

There can't be more than 1 results anyway since there is a Unique Key constranint, do I have to spell out the TOP(1) or whatever it is?

Note: I don't need LINQ answers, my question is how to write the **sql** script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a unique key constraint you do not need to add anything to have the FirstOrDefault behavior. For other queries you can add

> LIMIT 1

to the end of your SQL query. This will just give you the first answer which matches your constraints.

Edit after comment: To get it as a scalar in .NET you can use the [SQLCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method.

Comment: You mean that I can declare a scalar variable and select the results right to it. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I actually needed its ret value for a SQL Computed Column, but anyway, from your update I could understand that I wasn't wrong :) thanks a lot.